# running arbitrary system commands from Ruby, on OSX and Windows

Tags: ruby, execute

I would like to open OSX windows (and Windows windows) from a ruby script. If I do

```
system "touch /Users/apple/Documents/thekbase-temp-files/test5.txt"
```

it works (creates an empty file), but this

```
system "mate /Users/apple/Documents/thekbase-temp-files/test5.txt"
```

does not open TextMate, even though it does if I type it. I feel this might be a [version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012303/run-command-in-parent-shell-from-ruby) but I just want to be sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
system "open -a textmate /Users/apple/Documents/thekbase-temp-files/test5.txt"
```

Comment: Awesome. Now I'll improvise with cmd on my VirtualBox (Win XP) and if I get it running, I'll check the check mark. Thank you for responding!

Comment: Great. There it was system "cmd /c \\test5.txt" and I'm ready to rock. Thanks again, Chas.

Comment: On Windows, "cmd /c start some_file" is the equivalent to "open some_file" on OSX -- allowing the OS to launch the app with its default application.